# Android MediaPlayer can't stop

Tags: android, media-player

I have a code fragment in my BrocardcastReceiver like this:

```
if (cmd != null && cmd.equals(PLAY_SOUND)) { 
    Log.i("mp", "mp has already been prepared ");
    mp.setLooping(true); 
    mp.start(); 

    return;
}

if (cmd != null && cmd.equals(STOP_SOUND) && mp != null) {        
    if (mp.isLooping()) {
        mp.setLooping(false);
    }

    mp.stop(); 
    mp.release(); 

    return; 
}
```

It aims to control alarming or stop alarming. I can make `mp` run successfully, but when I want to stop it, `mp` is null. How can I stop `mp` from being changed?

Answer (score 0):

try this

in your code

```
       stopPlaying();
```

and declare this methode .

```
 private void stopPlaying() {
    if (player1 != null) {

        player1.stop();
        player1.release();
        player1 = null;
   }
}
```